# SQL count the number of comma-separated string match in another string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table in SQL Server with two columns as shown here, all number are comma-separated:

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
     [Sample] varchar(33), 
     Benchmark varchar(33)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES ('9,55,66', '55,44');
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES ('88,23,2,3,4', '23,88');
```

I need to match the data in `Sample` column with the `Benchmark`, then calculate the missing number ratio:

[image]

Let me explain:

- Column C means the number **55** exist in `Sample` and `Benchmark`
- Column D means only 1 match, which is 55
- Column E means total number exists in Benchmark = 2
- Column F is calculated `(2-1)/2 = 50%` of them are missing

I don't need column C, D ,E to be stored in the table, just a explanation purpose. WHAT I need is the column F.

I am using SQL Server 2019+.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Attach some sample data to make row constructors of and this might be a fun question to work on.

Comment: @Xedni  I attached a sample table.  please help

Comment: The solution would be to normalize your database. Anything other than that is just a workaround to handle a poor database design. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: I agree with @ZoharPeled 10000%. If you fix your design by normalizing it then your query will be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you're going to need a way to uniquely identify each of your rows. I could make the assumption that `sample` uniquely identifies the rows, but I'm sort of guessing there might be something like an `identity` on the table. if there isn't one, make one using `row_number()`. I simply added an identity called `Rid` to your temp table.

The reason you'll need this is you're going to split the samples and the benchmarks into two CTEs, call `string_split` on each of them, and then join them back together on the split value *and* the row identifier (in my example, `RID`, but again, if`sample` is a valid key, that works too.

The `samples` CTE is going to look like this:

```
select RID, Value = trim(b.value)
from #tmp a
cross apply string_split(a.sample, ',') b
```

and the `benchmarks` CTE is going to look like this:

```
select RID, Value = trim(b.value)
from #tmp a
cross apply string_split(a.benchmark, ',') b
```

I'm showing you these separately so you can see what each CTE contains. I'm also trimming the value in case there is whitespace in there. You could go a step further and cast them to `int` if you want/need, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Finally, left join everything back together on `RID` and `Value`, grouping by `RID` (i.e. the original row you were testing). The Benchmark count is just the total count of rows (or you could use `bm.value`; it's the same thing since `benchmarks` is your left table here) and the match count is the count of `s.value`. This works, because if there isn't a match, you'll get a null, and `count(s.value)` will skip any `s.value` where it's null.

```
;with samples as
(
    select RID, Value = trim(b.value)
    from #tmp a
    cross apply string_split(a.sample, ',') b
), benchmarks as
(
    select RID, Value = trim(b.value)
    from #tmp a
    cross apply string_split(a.benchmark, ',') b
)
select
    bm.RID,
    BenchmarkCount = count(1),
    MatchCount = count(s.value),
    MissingRatio = 100 - convert(decimal(9,3), (100.0 * count(s.Value)) / nullif(count(1), 0))
from benchmarks bm
left outer join samples s
    on bm.RID = s.RID
        and bm.Value = s.Value
group by bm.RID
```

From there, you can format your results however you like.

Answer (score 2):

Use [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to split the sample and benchmark CSV to rows. Then benchmark left join to sample.

```
with 
sample as
(
  select id, t.sample, t.benchmark, s.value
  from   your_table t
         cross apply string_split(t.sample, ',') s
),
benchmark as
(
  select id, t.sample, t.benchmark, s.value
  from   your_table t
         cross apply string_split(t.benchmark, ',') s
)
select b.sample, b.benchmark,
       [ratio] = (count(*) - count(s.value)) * 100.0 / count(*)
from   benchmark b
       left join sample s   on  b.id    = s.id
                            and b.value = s.value
group by b.sample, b.benchmark
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bPYPdNSK)

Comment: your code doesn't work. I attached a sample table.    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') is not null DROP TABLE #TempTable
create table #TempTable ([Sample] varchar(33), Benchmark varchar(33))
insert into #TempTable values ('9,55,66','55,44');
insert into #TempTable values ('88,23,2,3,4','23,88');

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: it works now, one question, how does this CROSS APPLY generate the s.value?  is it a special window function ?

Comment: that is the result of `string_split()`. Refer to documentation for further detail

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (CTEs) to compare values in two comma-separated columns (Sample and Benchmark) within the your_table table. It uses the STRING_SPLIT function to break these comma-separated values into individual rows. The query then calculates the number of unique matching values between the two columns and the total number of unique values in the benchmark column. Finally, it computes a missing ratio percentage for each row in the your_table table, representing the ratio of values in the Sample column that do not have a match in the Benchmark column. The result set includes all columns from the your_table table along with the calculated missing ratio.

```
WITH cte_sample AS (
    SELECT value AS sample_value
    FROM your_table
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Sample, ',')
),
cte_benchmark AS (
    SELECT value AS benchmark_value
    FROM your_table
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Benchmark, ',')
),
cte_matches AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.sample_value) AS num_matches
    FROM cte_sample s
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte_benchmark b
        WHERE b.benchmark_value = s.sample_value
    )
),
cte_total AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT benchmark_value) AS total_number
    FROM cte_benchmark
),
cte_final AS (
    SELECT
        yt.*,
        CAST(num_matches AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / NULLIF(total_number, 0) * 100 AS missing_ratio
    FROM your_table yt
    CROSS JOIN cte_matches
    CROSS JOIN cte_total
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_final;
```

Comment: @DaleK Thanks, I'll add an explanation. 
When should we use Cast explicitly? Multiplying with 1.0 is a good way or a Cast one?

Comment: Thanks, @DaleK, I got your point and updated the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,
   [missing ratio] = (1.0 * benchmark_count - match_count) / benchmark_count
from TempTable
cross apply (
    select string_agg(s.value, ','), count(*)
    from string_split(Sample, ',') s, string_split(Benchmark, ',') b
    where s.value = b.value) m(match, match_count)
cross apply (
    select count(*) from string_split(Benchmark, ',')) b(benchmark_count)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a805fa/7/0

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation in addition to a solution.

Comment: lovely thing about SQL is that it's self explanatory ;)

Comment: Not to a beginner... hence the need to add an explanation