SQL String Check between 2 lists
Each row I want to loop through each Basket SKU and check it against the Order SKUs.  The new column will count how many matches I have in each row.  Is this possible?
The Order Table is the following: [OrderNo] [SKU]
Basket Table is the following: [BasketNo] [SKU]
I used a view to create the BasketSKUs, OrderSKUs as comma separated.  I wasn't sure of the best way to check between the lists.  As noted below in the comments I have 290 baskets with a different amount of SKUs per basket and I will be checking against 1000s of orders at a time and each order will have a different amount of SKUs.
The expected results below is almost what I need.  I need it be in this format
[BasketID] [OrderNo] [ItemCount] [MatchCount]
Example Data



Basketld
OrderNo
BasketSKUs
OrderSKUs




20009610
MFTJZ3
064008,064011,064057,064074,064075,064092,064093,064094,064095,06...
226374,410990,561242,569197,630684,670071,685224,685225,685226,706226,706227,706228,706229,706230,706231,706232


20011137
MFTJZ3
856354,857133,857134,857135,857511,857512,857513,857530,857646,85...
226374,410990,561242,569197,630684,670071,685224,685225,685226,706226,706227,706228,706229,706230,706231,706232


20011138
MFTJZ3
055522,055523,055524,055525,089893,112935,119355,634691,634692,65...
226374,410990,561242,569197,630684,670071,685224,685225,685226,706226,706227,706228,706229,706230,706231,706232


20011139
MFTJZ3
055522,055523,055524,055525,089893,112935,119355,634691,634692,65...
055522,410990,561242,569197,630684,670071,685224,685225,685226,706226,706227,706228,706229,706230,706231,706232



I am having no luck with anything I have tried.
Expected results are:



Basketld
ItemCount
MatchCount




20009610
10
0


20011137
10
0


20011138
10
0


20011139
10
1




Please replace images with formatted text, tag your DBMS, and list desired output as formatted text.

Please provide both sample input data and expected result as tables with text, remove screenshots and url's. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Don't store values as comma delimited lists in the database.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575334/sql-count-the-number-of-comma-separated-string-match-in-another-string

Maybe we could use this fiddle version of your example to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Cgl2cUn-

I followed the example at SQL count the number of comma-separated string match in another string  and applied it to your examples.
CREATE TABLE Example 
    (
        Basketld    INT,
        OrderNo VARCHAR(512),
        BasketSKUs  VARCHAR(512),
        OrderSKUs   VARCHAR(512)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Example (Basketld, OrderNo, BasketSKUs, OrderSKUs) VALUES
        (20009610, 'MFTJZ3', '064008, 064011, 064057, 064074, 064075, 064092, 064093, 064094, 064095, 06...', '226374, 410990, 561242, 569197, 630684, 670071, 685224, 685225, 685226, 706226, 706227, 706228, 706229, 706230, 706231, 706232'),
        (20011137, 'MFTJZ3', '856354, 857133, 857134, 857135, 857511, 857512, 857513, 857530, 857646, 85...', '226374, 410990, 561242, 569197, 630684, 670071, 685224, 685225, 685226, 706226, 706227, 706228, 706229, 706230, 706231, 706232'),
        (20011138, 'MFTJZ3', '055522, 055523, 055524, 055525, 089893, 112935, 119355, 634691, 634692, 65...', '226374, 410990, 561242, 569197, 630684, 670071, 685224, 685225, 685226, 706226, 706227, 706228, 706229, 706230, 706231, 706232'),
        (20011139, 'MFTJZ3', '055522, 055523, 055524, 055525, 089893, 112935, 119355, 634691, 634692, 65...', '055522, 410990, 561242, 569197, 630684, 670071, 685224, 685225, 685226, 706226, 706227, 706228, 706229, 706230, 706231, 706232');
    
    SELECT * FROM Example
    
    ;with Baskets as
    (
      select Basketld,OrderNo, Value = trim(b.value)
      from Example a
      cross apply string_split(a.BasketSKUs, ',') b
    ), Orders as
    (
      select Basketld,OrderNo, Value = trim(b.value)
      from Example a
      cross apply string_split(a.OrderSKUs, ',') b
    )
    select
        b.Basketld,
        ItemCount = count(1),
        MatchCount = count(o.value)
    from Baskets b
    left outer join Orders o
        on b.Basketld = o.Basketld
            and b.Value = o.Value
    group by b.Basketld
    ORDER BY b.Basketld

fiddle



Basketld
ItemCount
MatchCount




20009610
10
0


20011137
10
0


20011138
10
0


20011139
10
1




This is RDBMS-specific code which means it's unlikely it matches OP's RDBMS and is on high risk to be absolutely useless for them. Better let them improve their question before answering.

The screenshot is from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

We don't know what. I've seen other DB tools which look exactly the same. Even if they use SQL Server, we don't know what version. Trim is for example not available in version 16 or earlier.

Sorry everyone.  This was my first time asking a question on here.  This is from SMSS.  I am using SQL Server 2016.  The database is not hosting the fields as comma delimited.  I created those fields in a view.  The screenshot was a output of a view I have started.  In essence I will have 2 tables of data and I need to check against.  Right now there are 290 baskets and could be thousands of orders I need to check each basket against each order and get a match count on each combination of the two.  Hope that helps.

I can't use string_split but I do have the original tables not delimited together.  I might have another solution that you helped me come up with tho however.  I won't finish it til tomorrow.

True. If you already have basket and order tables you don't need string_split.  This last part should help: select
b.Basketld,
ItemCount = count(1),
MatchCount = count(o.value)
from Baskets b
left outer join Orders o
on b.Basketld = o.Basketld
and b.Value = o.Value
group by b.Basketld
ORDER BY b.Basketld

Modifying your last statement slightly did get me what I needed and also dramatically sped up the query based on my original thought process.  Tx!
